# r.js - exclude some modules from compilation/minification process

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

While developing web app, I prefer to have performance closer to production quality. At the moment my little project is Requirejs based so I am trying accomplish my goal by using r.js. In one of cases I want to exclude some modules(files) from compilation/minification process, but I do not know how to do that. At the moment I have a next build script:

```
 ({
    mainConfigFile : "../app/js/main.js",
    appDir: "../app",
    baseUrl: "js",
    optimizeCss: "standard",
    fileExclusionRegExp: /\.git/,
    dir: "dist",
    modules: [
        {
            name: "main",
            exclude: [
                "infrastructure",
                "modules/app"

            ]
        }
    ]
})
```

So what I should do for excluding some modules(files), for example jquery module, from compilation/minification process ?

Comment: My current approach: 1)  compile/minify all project 2) replace some modules by un-compiled/un-minified versions (I am using gulp). Works fine but certenlly not the best solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the modules you wish to exclude to have the path `empty:`.

http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty

> If the script does not have any dependencies, or you do not want to include its dependencies or will be including them in another way, then you can use the special 'empty:' scheme in the paths config to just skip the file when doing an optimization.

An example build profile:

```
({
    baseUrl: ".",
    name: "main",
    out: "main-built.js",
    paths: {
        jquery: "empty:"
    }
})
```

Comment: I use the same solution to exclude 3rd party libs and it works fine.